# Integrating Twitter Api on ANDROID (using native api from twitter)

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterkit

Recently the Twitter kit is going to lose the support and I'm wondering what's is the right and recomended way to integrate to show feed tweets from search (using the api native or some new alternative to twitter kit) now and futter.

The most tutorial online is deprecated or uses twitter kit not work for some changes that Twitter made on your service and fails on oAuth.

The Question is how integrate twitter now in this year with the new native api on Android Api-28

If some one have a sample or start project I apreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Twitter4J? http://twitter4j.org/en/ It can be used with Android.

Comment: No, I tied with twitter kit , and for now I want to find a native implementation

Answer (score 3):

There are several alternative solutions for displaying Tweets in your app without Twitter Kit. You can render Embedded Tweets and Timelines within webviews using [Twitter for Websites](https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview). You can fork the Twitter Kit project and build it into your app, or copy the parts you need into your app. Or you can use [Twitter’s standard API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/tweets) to power your own native displays.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/). Right now there isn't any native Android libraries that work with Twitter's latest API. You can also directly call Twitter's API methods using any HTTP library, or an OAuth library such as [scribejava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava).

Answer (score 0):

Ok just for you ;) I just put on github a simple Android app test. It uses Twitter4J.
All you have to change is your twitter app credentials inside the file :

```
app/src/main/res/values/twitter_auth.xml
```

Here is the link :
https://github.com/jrevault/twitroid

Feel free to ask questions if you need.

Comment: I know this is a bad practice to put credentials there, but it is not the purpose of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You have do it easy with help of FCM , which provide all social Integration like
G+,Facebook,Twiter ....FCM having all facility ...